# Using email/password authentication with basic Firebase app, would like to add username

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm developing a basic messaging app with Firebase's built-in email/password authentication system.  I'd like to add a key value "username" option to the resultant authData payload as a message author identifier that's not the user's email address.

I've read the official documentation front to back and from all accounts, the idea is to migrate over to a custom token authentication system if you're adding custom data to the authData, but i'd really like to keep the existing auth system as is, unless I can continue to use the same auth information already resident in Firebase but just with a new custom token auth login.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you just leverage the standard method of adding a /users node to firebase which contains the users uid's as parent nodes then other data as children?  /users/uid_0/username: leroy    /users/uid_0/location: florida etc.

Comment: Thanks Jay.  I was leaning this way, but I just wanted to make sure I couldn't just package it in with the `auth` variable or `authData` payload.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot add custom attributes to the `authData` (or the `auth` variable in security rules) for the built-in email+password or OAuth providers. The common way around this limitation is as Jay commented to store the additional user data in your Firebase database under a `/users/$uid` node.

The only identity provider where you have control over the authData is when you use custom authentication.

Comment: This is preety intresting... How exactly do you use custom authentication?